# Can't get into my Downloads folder

Tags: macos

I am running `Mac 10.13.6 High Sierra` and my friend accidentally changed the **Open With** option for the **Downloads** folder to `TextEdit` and now if I double click on the Downloads icon from Macintosh HD, it opens up the `TextEdit` app with bunch of random characters.

I can still get to my Downloads folder via the left task pane but I just want to get it fixed. It is annoying to see a folder which usually has a blue thumbnail turn into a white icon sitting there.

**UPDATE**

After running `ls -leO@`, I get this output:

`Sadmans-MacBook-Pro:~ jiltedpotion$ ls -leO@
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 jiltedpotion  staff  -        64 Apr 25 01:39 AnacondaProjects
drwxr-xr-x   3 jiltedpotion  staff  -        96 Jul 24 03:09 AndroidStudioProjects
drwx------@  3 jiltedpotion  staff  -        96 Apr  5 06:21 Applications
    com.apple.quarantine      21 
drwxrwxr-x@  5 jiltedpotion  staff  -       160 Jun 21 21:14 Creative Cloud Files
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwx------+  8 jiltedpotion  staff  -       256 Jul 25 05:33 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 19 jiltedpotion  staff  -       608 Jul 13 04:28 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 19 jiltedpotion  staff  -       608 Jul 25 18:18 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 72 jiltedpotion  staff  hidden 2304 May  3 16:54 Library
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 16 jiltedpotion  staff  -       512 Jul 25 05:02 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  9 jiltedpotion  staff  -       288 Apr 11 21:11 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 46 jiltedpotion  staff  -      1472 Jul 14 03:27 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   7 jiltedpotion  admin  -       224 May 21 09:07 PromotionRes
drwxr-xr-x+  4 jiltedpotion  staff  -       128 Apr  2 22:05 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------   4 jiltedpotion  staff  -       128 Jul 25 05:02 VirtualBox VMs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jiltedpotion  staff  -        96 Apr  5 03:01 YoutubeDL`

When I click on **Downloads** in the Finder's sidebar, it takes me in the downloads folder without any problem. The problem begins if I try to go from Macintosh HD.

Comment: If someone wants further clarification, you could check out the situation here: https://imgur.com/a/nZjJ2QQ

Comment: I'm pretty sure something weirder than an "Open With" change has happened, but I'm not sure what. Can you open the Terminal utility, run the command "`ls -leO@`" (note: the "l" characters are lowercase letter L's, and the "O" is a capital letter O rather than zero). Then edit the output into your question, in code format (so it's readable). Also, what happens when you click the Downloads icon in the Finder's sidebar?

Comment: I'm with @GordonDavisson on this one. You don't get an 'open with' option on a folder, ever... unless something, somewhere, went badly wrong already.

Comment: I wonder if this is one of those rare situations where manually fixing permissions might actually fix the issue: sudo diskutil repairPermissions /

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Mac but my first instinct would be to revert what he did by changing the *open with...* back to it's default setting. Or you could try using a restore point to undo it if you so happen to conveniently have one. Again, i have no idea how Macs work, never owned one and i never plan to either.